# Reporting relative adjusted survival between categorical predictor's levels

Tags: survival, mortality

I'm looking for an option for reporting relative survival between categorical predictors' levels. It would very easy with Cox regression; however, I am using an AFT model as the proportional hazards assumption is violated.

**MODEL** (used [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/index.html))

```
m = flexsurvreg(Surv(time_12m, status_12m) ~ sex + age, dist="gengamma", data = data)
```

**MODEL'S SUMMARY**

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time_12m, status_12m) ~ sex + age, 
    data = data, dist = "gengamma")

Estimates: 
       data mean  est      L95%     U95%     se       exp(est)  L95%     U95%   
mu          NA    12.3055  11.6896  12.9213   0.3142       NA        NA       NA
sigma       NA     2.8587   2.7300   2.9935   0.0672       NA        NA       NA
Q           NA    -0.3773  -0.5381  -0.2166   0.0820       NA        NA       NA
sexm    0.2825    -0.8321  -0.9751  -0.6890   0.0730   0.4351    0.3772   0.5021
age    78.7817    -0.1075  -0.1144  -0.1007   0.0035   0.8981    0.8919   0.9042

N = 11491,  Events: 3534,  Censored: 7957
Total time at risk: 107331.9
Log-likelihood = -14203.32, df = 5
AIC = 28416.64
```

**AGE-ADJUSTED SURVIVAL CURVES FOR BOTH SEXES**

```
newdata = expand.grid(sex = c("f", "m"), age = median(data$age)

summary(m, newdata = newdata, type = "survival", ci = TRUE, tidy = T) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = time, y = est, color = sex, linetype = sex))+
  geom_line(size = 1)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl, fill = sex), alpha = 0.12, linetype = 0)
```

[image]

This plot seems really nice but it would be good to report relative survival in text format between the sexes at different time point. For example, males had two times lower probability for survival at three months. How to do it?

**OPTION A** - comparing restricted mean survivals at three months

```
  time      est      lcl      ucl sex age
1    3 2.739846 2.725196 2.753791   f  81
2    3 2.557144 2.524901 2.588812   m  81
```

2.74/2.56 = 1.07, males had 1.07 times higher survival at three months

**OPTION B**

Using the data used for plotting and comparing survival probabilities at three months as follows: 0.8527184/0.7672124 = 1.11

Males had 1.11 times lower survival probability at three months.

**QUESTIONS**

Are these options OK to use? Or what would be other options for describing relative survival between sexes?

Or should I use the model's coefficient for males to report the difference? The summary shows it for the whole follow-up period. How to calculate it for shorter time periods?